# Color a tree such that the weight multiplied with time is minimized

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

Given a binary tree, with n nodes and each node having weight wi (i denotes the weight for ith node),we have to color each node of the tree . The cost of coloring the node is equal to the weight of the node multiplied by the time it was colored. The time starts with 1 and increments by 1 as you continue coloring the nodes . While coloring its mandatory that the parent gets colored before the child . Calculate the minimum cost for coloring the whole tree ?

Comment: What is the "time it was colored"?

Comment: Hi @Henry , I made an edit to the question . Each time the node gets colored the time increments by 1 and start value of time is 1.

Comment: Can we color 2 nodes at the same level at the same time?

Comment: No, you cannot. Only one node can be coloured at a time.

Comment: Please specify what you have tried so far and what problems are you facing..

Comment: Are there constraining properties of the tree (for example, is it balanced), or is it just arbitrary? Can the nodes contain additional information beyond Wi, for example max depth w/ direction, or weight of the child sub-trees? Needless to say, with these constraints and/or additional information, there are sorting & divide-and-conquer (DP) approaches that can be taken. If the tree is explicitly arbitrary and you cannot modify the contents of the nodes, this problem becomes NP-Hard, and any heuristic search will have horrible failure-modes.

Comment: @ArnabRoy I faced this question in a online interview challenge. Was clueless of how to approach except applying greedy approach which would result in failure .

Comment: @jhill515 n<=100 and maximum wi<=1000. Apart from this no additional information was given.

Comment: Is it expressly time increments by 1 at moment of coloring, or both color and visit (just trying to get clarification)? What I mean is, is it possible to search down a branch without coloring to compute subtree weights?

Answer (score 0):

In the research literature, this problem is to schedule jobs with precedence on a single machine to minimize total weighted completion time. There's an O(n log n) algorithm for series-parallel precedence due to Lawler. Let me summarize it below in the special case of trees.

If there were no requirement that parents be scheduled before their children, then we'd want to color in order of non-increasing weight. Lawler's procedure works bottom-up, combining nodes into what I'll call composite nodes. The output at each node x is a set of composite nodes that (1) contains each descendant of x exactly once (2) can be colored in non-decreasing order of weight (where the weight of a composite node is the mean weight of its constituent nodes) without violating the parent-child ordering constraints.

At each node x in post order, first merge the sets from x's children. While there exists a composite node in the merged set that's at least as heavy as x, pop that node out and replace x by a composite consisting of x and that node. For efficiency, represent the sets as as mergeable priority queue (e.g., pairing heaps).

Finally, sort the composite nodes and flatten them into a list.

Comment: Please see comments above... Parallelism was expressly forbidden as a requirement (see @vivek_23's comment and the response). Likewise, parents are scheduled prior to children. Subtree descriptions (that is weight of subsequent nodes or their aggregation) are excluded.

Comment: @jhill515 Yes, I saw all of those comments. This algorithm produces a sequential schedule with parents before children.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is that you can traverse the tree level by level. Sort the entire level, then colour each of the nodes in such a way that their sum is minimum. Repeat this for every level.

For illustration, if you have the following tree:

```
      4
     / \
    3   7
       / \
      1   9
     /
    2
```

1. Retrieve the first level: `4`.
2. Sort it in descending order. and Multiply by `time`: `4*1`. Cost = 4.
3. Retrieve 2nd level: `3  7`.
4. Sort it in descending order. and multiply each node by `time`: `7*2 + 3*3 = 23`. Cost = 4 + 23 = 27.
5. Retrieve 3rd level: `1 9`
6. Sort it in descending order. and multiply each node by `time`: `9*4+1*5 = 41`. Cost = 27 + 41 = 68.
7. Retrieve 4th level: `2`
8. Sort it in descending order. and multiply each node by `time`: `2*6 = 12`. Cost = 68 + 12 = 80.

How to traverse a binary tree in level order fashion. Please refer this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/level-order-tree-traversal/